# Timer gives 2 values when it stops

Tags: java, for-loop, random, timer

When the requestTime == 0 I get 2 results. I've printed "luck" into the for loop and it loops for 5 seconds but the thing is when it reaches 0 it prints two results. I get one result from the System.out which is in the if(requestTime == 0 ) then my for loop runs 1 more and I get another System.out (an updated one) from if(requestTime == 0 ) How can I fix this? I need to get the FINAL value. A friend told me I could use arrays but I have no idea how. I need to calculate inside the for loop and print the SUM of the values.

```
   //TIMER METHOD
 static int requestTime = 5;
 public static void randomN () {
      myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
              public void run() {
                     if(requestTime > 0)
               {
                   requestTime--;
               }
               else myTimer.cancel();

               int nTimesRandom = (int) (Math.random()*6+1);
               for (int i=0; i<nTimesRandom; i++) {
                   int rx = (int) (Math.random()*10+1); 
                   int ry = (int) (Math.random()*10+1); 
                   a = a+nTimesRandom;

               if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((a1x1-rx),2)+Math.pow((a1y1-ry),2))<3) {
                 reached1++;
                 if ( cap1 < 3 ) { cap1++; }
                 else if ( cap1 == 3 ) { nreached1++; }
               }
               else { oor++; }
               if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((a2x2-rx),2)+Math.pow((a2y2-ry),2))<3) {
                 reached2++;
                 if ( cap2 < 3 ) { cap2++; }
                 else if ( cap2 == 3 ) { nreached2++; }
               }
               else { oor++; }
               if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((a3x3-rx),2)+Math.pow((a3y3-ry),2))<3) {
                 reached3++;
                 if ( cap3 < 3 ) { cap3++; }
                 else if ( cap3 == 3 ) { nreached3++; }
               }
               else { oor++; }
               System.out.println("luck");

               }
                oor = a -( reached1+reached2+reached3) ;
                int totalreached = reached1+reached2+reached3 ; 
                if ( requestTime == 0 ) { 
                  System.out.println( a + " communication requests were generated, " + totalreached + " of them were served, " + oor + " of them were unserved."); }
                 // System.out.println("Requests " + "X : " + rx + " Y: " + ry);


               }
      }, 0, 1000);

}
```

My console output is like this :

...

luck

...

142 communication requests were generated, 20 of them were served, 122 of them were unserved.

luck

luck

luck

luck

158 communication requests were generated, 23 of them were served, 135 of them were unserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the request time is `> 0`, then you decrement requestTime, and then execute the rest of the method. So when requestTime is 1, it becomes 0, and then the rest of the code is executed.

If the request time is `== 0`, then you **don't** decrement requestTime, and then execute the rest of the method. So it stays at 0, and then the rest of the code is executed.

I guess that you either want to decrement always, or to avoid the execution of the rest of the code if requestTime is == 0.